# How do I replace the '&#x5c' with '/' in file using the command line?

Tags: text-processing, replace, xml

After `grep` line with `AAA/BBB/CCC` but the output file consists only the line as `AAA"& #x5c;"BBB"& #x5c;"CCC`..

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you add example input and output at least, so we know what we're to be helping you deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your output is in some way encoded. You can try to pipe the output from `grep` through `sed`, it that is the only sequence you have to change:

```
echo 'AAA"& #x5c;"BBB"& #x5c;"CCC' | sed 's/"& #x5c;"/\//g'
```

will give you

```
AAA/BBB/CCC
```

Comment: That's not URL encoding. Without the space, it's HTML (or XML or XHTML) character reference http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#character-references -- but `&#x5c;` represents backslash `\ ` NOT normal slash `/` which would be `&#x2f;`.